# Sentence Clustering in Python not using the Vector representation

Tags: cluster-analysis

I want to perform sentence clustering using k means in python. I am not representing the sentences in vector form. I performed the sentence segmentation using nltk and having a list of sentences.Now how do I represent the initial cluster centroids (say i want k=3)?

Comment: @chouaib

sentlist = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
for s in sent:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
        symbols = ['.',',',';','"','(',')','\'']
        word = [w for w in words if not w.lower() in stopwords.words('english') and not w in symbols]
        wordlist.append(word)
Having a list of tokenized sentences in 'wordlist', i want to perform clustering on this list

Comment: no one will bother reading your comment! please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

### k-means only works for vector data

As the name suggests, it *must* be able to compute the *mean*.

How would you compute the mean of "apple" and "orange"?

Furthermore, the *mean* must also minimize the objective function. For numerical data, the mean is a least-squares estimator, it minimizes sum-of-squares. Thus, k-means with squared Euclidean distance is fine; but other distances may fail to converge (see other questions for examples of this happening).

K-means is **variance minimization**. This is a concept that only applies to continuous numerical variables. It's already questionable on integer or binary variables (it will work there, but the result will often be meaningless). On text - no way.

### Don't expect clustering algorithms to work magic.

You can't just throw your text into a clustering algorithm and expect magic to happen. To get meaningful results, you need to be very explicit about your assumptions and objectives. Double-check them, get them into an algorithm, run the algorithm, and evaluate the result very carefully again.

An clustering algorithm that isn't fed with assumptions is useless. Why should it cluster "apple" and "orange", and not "apple" and "samsung"? **You need to give directions on *what* is a good cluster for you.** This is very much user- and data dependant.